# Applying class to Ajax-loaded content not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's my function to load my content:

```
$("#site-nav .nav1").on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
    $('ul.top-level').load('assets/includes/recent.php', function () {
        $(this).show();
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

That content loads into `ul.top-level` fine.

Once that content is loaded, I attempt to apply a class to any of the hrefs in the newly-loaded content:

```
$("ul.top-level li a").on('click', function () {
    alert("hi");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
});
```

This does not work, nor does the alert message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be worth noting where you apply the new `click` handlers, because there's a good chance that the dom isn't ready when you're trying to attach them. However, you could probably solve this by using [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead.

`live()` applies to all future matched selectors, so if you load ajax content it should attach the click handlers to them automatically.

```
$("ul.top-level li a").live('click', function () {
    alert("hi");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
});
```

Edit: Since `live()` is deprecated, you can rewrite live using `on()` instead as such:

```
$(document).on('click', "ul.top-level li a", function () {
    alert("hi");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I thought `live()`was deprecated which is why I was using `on()`?

Comment: It is indeed, so you could use `$(document).on("click", "ul.top-level li a", function(){ alert("hi"); });` instead.

Comment: Thanks, i switched it to `$("ul.top-level").on('click', "ul.top-level li a", function (e) {...});`and that did the trick.